# How to address snide remarks about an OS?

Tags: discussion, answers

[I recently asked a question about an issue I was having with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879185/cant-use-git-add-with-patch-option). I believe the question was a legitimate one, and I and made every attempt to include all the pertinent details about my computer, operating system, version of Git, etc.

I received several answers, and while all of them at least attempted to address the question, literally every one did so only after a snide remark along the lines of "Your problem is that you're using Windows." At least one additional comment began with such a remark as well.

These comments are irrelevant, unhelpful, and derogatory. Are such comments considered acceptable for Stack Overflow? Is there anything I can do to discourage them besides down-voting? When every single answer to a question contains this cruft, I feel that it hurts the usefulness of the site and makes it more difficult to find real answers.

Comment: Oh wait..... by "comments" you mean comments in answers, not comments-comments? Then just shrug em off

Comment: Windows certainly *can* be the source of a problem, as could any OS. If it's not relevant, editing it out wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the OS might really be at fault? I don't know much about the intricacies of Git but having a software behaving differently depending on the OS doesn't sound weird at all.

Comment: @Tunaki If it is, no one explained *why*, but merely asserted "I wouldn't use Windows", "your first mistake was windows", "you're *[sic]* best bet is to not use Windows". That's not helpful at all. IMHO the first mistake was using `git`. Can I add my answer now?

Comment: In my opinion comments like "Your problem is that you're using Windows." Is just noise and don't contribute anything of value. Maybe the answers should be edited to remove the irrelevant parts.

Comment: Sure, Windows could theoretically be at fault.  But these answers didn't include any explanation of how that might specifically be the case here, or reasons why the answerer thought so.  They were the typical looking-down-one's-nose at other OSes.  An explanation of, say, a known Windows issue that pertains to the question would have beeen helpful.  These remarks are not helpful.

Comment: @CarlFink which is why Alexander said editing it out wouldn't hurt. It's not part of their answer and therefore an edit removing that noise is appropriate. Now... for the "snideness" of it.... there's no 12 solutions here.... just don't let these impact you... it's not worth the aggravation

Comment: Suck it up, buttercup. People are jealous of us master PC race folks. You'll just have to deal with all that privilege.

Comment: @Will As apposed to what, non-personal computers?

Comment: @BradLarson Any comment on why two of the accounts were destroyed?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - Nothing at all suspicious about three new accounts with similar names posting pretty much the same answer, with the same anti-Windows comment, within a half hour and then all three getting upvoted by the same amount.

Comment: @BradLarson Yeah, that was my suspicion, but I didn't want to presume.

Comment: An even better question than what you've asked here, would be "why are you using windows?"

Comment: They could have picked a way better meme than anti-Windows...

Comment: I guess that they are using Windows because it's too much of a pain to run a VM just for Linux and git, what with all the shared files, samba etc hassle.  Still, if the aternative is plain Linux, with its non-existent or un-installable packages, missing libs/paths, ll, chmod, chown, and drivers from the last century, then the VM path may be best.

Comment: That said, it seems plain that the Windows 'releases' of git and its tools are some sort of punishment duty at git.  What I've seen of it is utter crap from 'developers' who can only understand text on consoles and could not build a decent GUI if a Euromilions win came with it:(

Comment: @MartinJames A CLI: Where the amount of text written to complain about it, always exceeds the amount of text it takes to actually use it. Git was originally developed for use with the Linux kernel, I would say any other platforms it was ported to are a gift, not punishment. If you feel so strongly there should be a GUI, why don't you develop it?

Comment: Wow - that had to be seen to be believed! It's a shame such an anti-windows stigma still exists. Microsoft are making massive steps forward (and though they do things I don't always like) they're really trying to be responsive to the development community - so it's a shame these attitudes still exist.

Comment: Windows is a problem using git because it does not support git natively, these are all valid comments. Most peoples problems with git on Windows are Windows related problems and **not** git related otherwise they would be problems on Linux and OSX as well. Your particular problem is rooted in **Windows** not in git, so suck it up, the don't use Windows are valid answers.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Neither Linux nor OSX supports git any more "natively" than does Windows.  Git is an external application that has been created for and is available on multiple platforms.  It's possible that the Windows version of Git contains some quirk that other versions don't, but that's still a problem with Git, not with Windows.  And even that being the case, the comments in question don't have any evidence to suggest that it's the case, which would be useful information.  They just contain sophomoric "my OS is better than your OS" noise.

Comment: So when you can load up the git source into Visual Studio and compile and run it without having to use cygwin you will be correct. Right now, git has dependencies that are not provided by Windows.

Comment: That still doesn't address the problem that those answers didn't contain any actual information or evidence that the problem I was experiencing was related to those dependencies.  They were just juvenile, information-free non-answers.

Comment: The problems are with the brain dead way the Windows Filesystem, unrelated to Git because those issues are not a problem on Linux or OSX because the accepted answer is about the cygwin conversion which is only required under Windows. Thus Windows problem.

Comment: Except the answers in question *didn't say that*.  "The Windows version of Git doesn't work as expected under these circumstances because of XXX" would have been a great answer.  "Don't use Windows" is a very poor answer.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Honestly, I am somewhat disappointed at those answers. But at the same time, they're all from low-reputation fairly new users... So I hope you don't judge *all* of the the Stack Overflow *community* on just that :-/

Snide comments about "I wouldn't use Windows" add nothing. It *might* be a appropriate to say "Please be aware that git doesn't work very well on Windows because [foo], I wouldn't use Windows for this" though. But this is not really applicable here, since git works perfectly fine on Windows.

- Comments can be flagged with "not constructive". Away with them!
- All the answers *do* actually attempt to answer the question, so that's good. You can **edit** them and remove the remarks. Your changes won't show up immediately, but have to go through a review where other Stack Overflow members can approve (or decline) your changes. They will almost certainly be approved, but if it's not, and you're *really* bothered by it, you can flag the answer for moderator attention and explain that you tried to edit out an inappropriate snide remark and that it was rejected.

All those remarks have been removed from the answers.

Comment: In this case, I think they might be a crass way of saying "This issue is a Windows-specific problem, so you need a workaround if you want to do this with Windows."

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Yup, that's possible and perhaps even likely. It was phrased terribly though ;-)

Comment: "But at the same time, they're all from low-reputation fairly new users" - Ummm...that smells like a snide remark. Civility is one of my personal bugaboos on these Internets Tubes. I've nuked almost every social media account I've ever had, because I got sick of the churlish crap. This site is pretty darn good about this. No outright trolls, but I have seen some pretty awful stuff, usually delivered as patronizing, condescending zingers in comments. Sometimes, folks downvote because of personal issues, but not so often. TL;DR: Golden Rule. Do unto others... and so on. Have a great day! :)

Comment: BTW: I am quite familiar with OS bullying. I tend to program Macs and iOS devices. Have been for nearly 30 years. It can get me some serious hate.

Comment: @MAGNAWS Well, the quote continues with "So I hope you don't judge all of the the Stack Overflow community on just that"... In other words, my point was merely to emphasize that three new users (who later in fact turned out to be three accounts belonging to a single person) do not represent the Stack Overflow community as a whole or the standing etiquette surrounding these matters. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 10):

It happens only very occasionally; never goes much beyond the silly M$ putdown.  Dusted off pretty well by [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6189/144883). Far too rare to be concerned about. This site is visited by professional developers and none of them give a hoot what OS you (must) use.

Let's be clear what happened here. As Brad noted, these posts were just from a *single* user, who used sock puppet accounts to make them look like they were from different users and cross-voted them to pretend they were helpful. That's very easy to do. Such users are *not* representative of SO: anybody can post an answer and that does get abused by riff raff some times. For all we know, it is a 14 year old kid that wants to look cool with his geeky friends. Not a professional — just ignore such crap.